# How to check image ready for set boot mode in SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I had created 'Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group' from from external source and got the object id(such as 12345678).

And I POST `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/12345678/setBootMode.json`.

It returned an error like below:

```
{
  "error": "Unable to find the primary block device of this image template.",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception"
}
```

But I waited a few time and try again it worked to set boot mode.

So my question is that: Do we have a function to check the image ready for set boot mode?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that ID obtained previously and use the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::getObject, along with object masks you could verify if there´s a transaction pending by viewing the transactionId property set with a value (e.g.: 48259234), when this value returns "null" then you would be able to use other functions (as setBootMode).

Try the following:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/12345678/getObject?objectMask=mask[children[transaction[transactionGroup]]]
```

Request above will fill data for transaction and transactionGroup objects, but as mentioned previously, when the transactionId is null, these will not be returned in the response and transactionId will be set as "null".